# What's wrong with this tzinfo variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this line of code:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0, "<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>")
```

And it keeps giving me this error:

```
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'
```

What is `tzinfo` and where does it go?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error is somewhat self-explanatory: `tzinfo` argument requires a `tzinfo` object rather than a string. I would advise using `pytz`, however. `pytz` is much more robust than the standard library's support for time zones. You can install it with `pip install pytz`. See [the docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for more info.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> d = datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
>>> pacific = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
>>> pacific
<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>
>>> pacific_date = pacific.localize(d)
>>> pacific_date
datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 17, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
```

Comment: note: using `.localize()` may introduce  [ambiguity in the results](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime). [Convert the timestamp to utc datetime object and then convert it to the given timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23051332/4279) to avoid it.

Answer (score 11):

To convert POSIX timestamp to the local timezone e.g., `'US/Pacific'`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

timestamp = 0 # seconds since the Epoch
local_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.timezone('US/Pacific'))
```